# ImageMagick and adding a visual watermark

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am currently trying to work with ImageMagick and teaching myself as I go.

I have managed to get images to upload and then be converted size wise, and append some text to them, but I ideally need to append a logo to them.

I have been reading through the documentation via the ImageMagick website but feel I am making stupid mistakes now.

This is the code I have for the ImageMagick command, can anyone shed some light on what I actually need to do to fix this?

```
$cmd = 'mogrify -composite -disolve 25% -gravity southwest watermark_new.png '.$thefile.' '.$thefile.'';
```

Thanks for all the help guys.

THIS FIXED THE PROBLEM:

```
$cmd = 'mogrify -gravity southwest -geometry +30+30 -draw "image Over 0,0 '.$width.','.$height.' \''.$watermark.'\'" '.$thefile;
```

Comment: if anyone is going to be able to help you "fix" it you need to say whats actually wrong

Comment: Sure... Will remember that minor detail next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you need the mogrify part - the command you're actually looking to use is `composite` - have you tried:

```
$cmd = 'composite -disolve 25% -gravity southwest watermark_new.png '.$thefile.' '.$thefile.'';
```

Theres a number of examples [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_image)